# Support sharing model changes in subscribe org as ISV

Tags: managed-package, sharing, isv

We are an ISV developing a Managed Package.

We wrote some Unit tests that do things like (this is an Example)

```
Custom_Object__c a = new Custom_Object__c(Name = 'Test');
insert a;

Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='Standard User'];
        User usr = new User(Alias = 'standt', Email= 'somerandomEmail@here.com',
                            EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='Testing', 
                            LanguageLocaleKey='en_US',
                            LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = p.Id,
                            TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', 
                            UserName= 'somerandomUsername@here.com');

        insert usr;
    System.runAs(usr) {
      a.Name = 'testxxx';
      update a;
    }
```

In our dev org, the sharing model for `Custom_Object__c` is `Public Read/Write`. However, some customers in some of their orgs run with `Private` Sharing model.

When we run our tests in their orgs, they fail.

However, if we switch our dev org to `Private` and amend the tests like so

```
Custom_Object__c a = new Custom_Object__c(Name = 'Test');
insert a;

Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='Standard User'];
        User usr = new User(Alias = 'standt', Email= 'somerandomEmail@here.com',
                            EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='Testing', 
                            LanguageLocaleKey='en_US',
                            LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = p.Id,
                            TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', 
                            UserName= 'somerandomUsername@here.com');

        insert usr;

UserRecordAccess ura = [SELECT HasEditAccess, RecordId FROM UserRecordAccess WHERE UserId = :usr.Id AND RecordId = :a.Id];

            if (!ura.HasEditAccess) {
                Custom_Object__Share share = new Custom_Object__Share (ParentId = t.Id, UserOrGroupId = usr.Id, AccessLevel = 'Edit');
                insert share;
            }

    System.runAs(usr) {
      a.Name = 'testxxx';
      update a;
    }
```

Then switching back to `Public Read/Write` fails because

> Error: Unable to change sharing model because sharing objects are referenced by the following components:

How are we meant to support both sharing models as an ISV?

Ideally we want to baseline our package on `Public Read/Write` but then we also want our tests not fail if the customer has changed to `Private` or `Public Read Only`.

Comment: Have you tried to use Type.forName in order to dynamically create share record without referencing that explicitly?

Answer (score 1):

If you want this unit test user with the Standard User profile to have full read/write capabilities, I'd suggest creating a [`PermissionSet`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfFieldRef.meta/sfFieldRef/salesforce_field_reference_PermissionSet.htm), adding object permissions to that Permission Set via [`ObjectPermissions`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_objectpermissions.htm), then assign it to this unit test user via [`PermissionSetAssignment`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfFieldRef.meta/sfFieldRef/salesforce_field_reference_PermissionSetAssignment.htm).  All of these are standard objects of which you can use regular DML commands to create and work with.

Something along these lines:

```
// Create new Permission Set for your unit test user
PermissionSet ps = new PermissionSet(
    Label='Custom Object Perms',
    Name='Custom_Object_Perms',
    Description='Gives permissions to read/write on Custom Object'
);
insert ps;

// Assign read/write permissions to this new Permission Set
ObjectPermissions op = new ObjectPermissions(
    ParentId = ps.Id,
    SobjectType = 'Custom_Object__c',
    PermissionsViewAllRecords = true,
    PermissionsModifyAllRecords = true
    // Add any other permissions on the object you'd like...
);
insert op;

// Assign the Permission Set to your unit test user
PermissionSetAssignment psa = new PermissionSetAssignment(
    PermissionSetId = ps.Id,
    AssigneeId = usr.Id
);
insert psa;
```

**NOTE**: I'm not sure if creating this `PermissionSet` actually creates the Permission Set permanently in the org via the unit test.  Worth testing, and you could always delete the `PermissionSetAssignments` and `PermissionSet` at the end of your unit test method.

**Update 3/10**: As confirmed by @sfdcfox, no data persists after the unit test, including all these Permission Set related objects, so you don't have to worry about cleaning up the data.

Comment: No data ever persists beyond the end of a unit test. There was a bug where Platform Event triggers were doing this, but that's been fixed. It's perfectly safe to do what you describe.

Comment: @sfdcfox Thanks for confirming - I'll update my post to remove that note